# Long page loading with own script js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a page that takes a long time to load.

The reason is the js script code.

I set it to load asynchronously but it doesn't help.

Is there a way to do this? (In the script, I also refer to the Model from view.)

PageView:

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        //Lots of code with functions and references to DOM and AJAX
    </script>
}
```

_Layout:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
{
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", true)
}
```

The server returns a timeout error (works locally without any problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defer` attribute `<script defer> ... </script>`.
Also do you used `await` a lot?

Answer (score 0):

I use this syntax, wtihtout any problem

```
 @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```